# Meta Ad Library API does not return any ad for specefic page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I have connected my application into Facebook Ad Library API using https calls.
It is working fine on some pages. but in some other pages it does not return all pages ads or in some it does not return any! but when you take a look at the page itself in the Facebook Ad Library Website. It is showing the page ads.
An example of this would be Hunger Games page which is at url `https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=ALL&view_all_page_id=159746560708670&search_type=page&media_type=all` and you can see that it is displaying more than 20 ads in the page but when you try to get its ads from the Ads Library API. it returns `{"data":[]}`. My code to get the ads from Facebook Library API is.

```js
const axios = require('axios');

let config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/ads_archive?ad_type=ALL&ad_reached_countries=["AD","AE","AG","AI","AL","AM","AO","AQ","AR","AT","AU","AZ","BA","BB","BD","BE","BF","BG","BH","BI","BJ","BM","BN","BO","BR","BS","BT","BV","BW","BY","BZ","CA","CD","CF","CG","CH","CI","CL","CM","CO","CR","CV","CY","CZ","DE","DJ","DK","DM","DO","DZ","EC","EE","EG","ER","ES","ET","FI","FJ","FK","FM","FR","GA","GB","GD","GE","GG","GH","GI","GM","GN","GQ","GR","GS","GT","GW","GY","HN","HR","HT","HU","ID","IE","IL","IM","IN","IO","IQ","IS","IT","JE","JM","JO","JP","KE","KG","KH","KI","KM","KN","KW","KY","KZ","LA","LB","LC","LI","LK","LR","LS","LT","LU","LV","LY","MA","MC","MD","ME","MG","MH","MK","ML","MM","MN","MR","MS","MT","MU","MV","MW","MX","MY","MZ","NA","NE","NG","NI","NL","NO","NP","NR","NZ","OM","PA","PE","PG","PH","PK","PL","PN","PS","PT","PW","PY","QA","RO","RS","RW","SA","SB","SC","SE","SG","SH","SI","SK","SL","SM","SN","SO","SR","SS","ST","SV","SZ","TC","TD","TG","TH","TJ","TL","TM","TN","TO","TR","TT","TV","TW","TZ","UA","UG","US","UY","UZ","VA","VC","VE","VG","VN","VU","WS","XK","YE","ZA","ZM","ZW"]&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&ad_active_status=ALL&media_type=ALL&search_page_ids=159746560708670'
};

axios.request(config)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

I have also noticed that when i pass `ALL` instead of an array of all reached countries in
`ad_reached_countries` param. it would not return any ads and i have to put all possible countries in the value. I have tried so many ways to solve this problem but its not working.
I have also tried FB Graph Explorer and its [Radlibrary](https://facebookresearch.github.io/Radlibrary) or its [Ad Library API script repository](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Ad-Library-API-Script-Repository) but none of them return the expected results.
Is there any way that i can solve this problem ?